# Calculate likelihood of soccer player to intercept pass

Tags: math

I am working on a soccer game engine in C#, and specifically the safety of a pass along the ground.  I'm having a hard time thinking of a suitable formula to indicate how far an opposing player might be from intercepting a pass.  I want to be able to give a likelihood between 0 and 1, ignoring all other factors like ball height, player pace/ability/etc.  In other words, I'm thinking mostly about current position of the opposing player.

What formula would you deem most appropriate?  Perhaps an arc with the possession player at the centre and the recipient player on the radius?

Comment: If you ignore speed of the ball and the player and limit it to two dimensions, then it's only whether the two lines intersect. Math wise that's solving two simulataneous equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, wouldn't something along the following lines work: imagine a player A is about to pass the ball to the player B and then there's a player C trying to intercept the pass. Since you want to ignore variables like ball height, you'll only need some rather simple 2-dimensional math for this.

Have a line segment AB from point A to point B. If player C wants to intercept the pass, he is most likely to do that at a point P that belongs to the line segment AB and has the closest distance to the point C. The player C will be able to intercept the pass if he can move from point C to point P before the ball can move from point A to point P. Again, this is trivial to find out, you just need to know the velocity of the ball and the velocity of the opposing player trying to intercept the pass.

Now, if you knew, let's say the mean and the standard deviation of both the speed of the passes and the opposing player and the average chance for a player to intercept a pass succesfully if he can get there in time, you could apply some statistics to get some pseudo-meaningful estimates out.

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps a percentage is not the best approach to take here.  Treat it first as a binary scenario (intercepted or safe) and then apply randomness based on the ability of the two players involved and the passing accuracy.